# User has to stop processing input after the cumulative sum of all the input becomes negative

Tags: java

My code is running fine but it is passing only 2 test cases out of 4 .could anyone tell me the error in my code.

Constraint-All numbers input are integers between -1000 and 1000.

Input-
1
2
88
-100
49

Output-
1
2
88

My code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cumulative_sum 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum=0,x,i=0;
        int[] arr=new int[9];
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
         x=sc.nextInt();
         arr[i]=x;
         if(sum+arr[i]<0)
                break;
         i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1 + 2 + 88 = 91, 91 - 100 = -9 => Isn't that what you want? This code terminates at the right moment.

Comment: You don't even need an array. You could also track just the total: `int total = 0; while (sc.hasNextInt()) { int num = sc.nextInt(); if (total + num < 0) { break; } total += num; System.out.println(total); }`

Comment: well I think what you need is this -> Your current code store the input first and then check for the whether the commutative sum is less than 0. `Resulting in  -100 in output array`. If you don't need that, then rather than checking it after Inserting. Check it before that if that number could result in negative sum or not

Comment: `if(sum+arr[i]>=0) arr[i]=x; else break;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of the code without using arrays (making your life easier): in the given problem, we need to simply ask the user for the input till the cumulative sum gets negative.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int sum = 0;

        while(scn.hasNextInt())
        {
            n = scn.nextInt();
            sum = sum + n;
            if(n > -1000 && n < 1000)
            {
                if(sum >= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```